# How to keep log-shipping up after failover (mirroring) in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mirroring, log-shipping

In SQL Server 2008,I have three instances which are LOG-SHIP, PROD, and MIRROR and I keep my transaction logs on different disks.

For instance my PROD transaction file is located under C:\MSSQL10.PROD\MSSQL\TRAN_PROD. , MIRROR transaction file is located under C:\MSSQL10.PROD\MSSQL\TRAN_MIRROR and lastly LOG-SHIP transaction file is located under C:\MSSQL10.PROD\MSSQL\TRAN_LOGSHIP

As you can guess there is mirroring between PROD and MIRROR. In addition, There is log-shipping between PROD and LOG-SHIP.

**What I want to learn is this :**

Once I failover between databases which are PROD and MIRROR, PROD act as MIRROR and MIRROR act as PROD as we can expect.

In MIRROR database (which is PROD now after failover), it can backup log files by means of bakup_log job. But the job of LOG-SHIP instance can not copy transaction logs due to changed network path. Thus i need to set-up log-shipping between LOG-SHIP and the instance which is currently used as PROD. Instead of setting up log shipping what i can do in order to automate the system. In other word, i just want to make small changes after this failover issue and make the system up again.

Comment: You are better off asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28954/muhammed-ali